# Error in Model classes after creating Model.Context and Model classes in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have generated xxxModel.Context and xxxModel template (in Models) from an **existing database** using EF 4.1 on ASP.Net MVC 4 application. After that when I build the project it gives the error for all the Model classes (POCO) saying "The type **file name** already contains a definition for **memeber variable name**". Where am I going wrong?

[image: Screen shot for the error!]

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the file `DESE.cs` (and others) already contains identically named classes with properties - which are clashing with the types generated by EF.  `CC_Names.cs`, for example, is being output by a text template - so I'm assuming you've got more than one code-generation strategy going on here from the same database.

And then you also have issues where you've re-declared the partial class `CorpCostEntities` again in another file with a different base to the one set by the EF code generator.

I think you might need to decide whether you want to use edmx code generation or the text-templating approach and stick to it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am bit confused about the code generation and text-templating. I first generated the DB model by .dmx and then used "Add code generation item" from the .edmx file to generate the POCO classes. Because when I generated the .edmx the .cs file under the .edmx showed the following message.

Comment: // Default code generation is disabled for model 'C:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Diaverum\BIReport\Models\BIReport.edmx'. 
// To enable default code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
// property to an alternate value. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model is
// open in the designer.

Comment: ah I got it now. I changed the value to default for "Code Generation Strategy" and then Designer.cs class generated all the code. Thank you so much for the help @Andras